# Chaining commands with xargs

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

I am trying to accomplish the following result with bash:

1. `grep` files for some substring.
2. take the filenames (which can contain spaces) for these files and print them.
3. after printing each filename I want to grep again, however this time inside that file only.

So the result looks like this:

```
/tmp/file1.txt
it works!
/tmp/file2.txt
/tmp/file3.txt
it works!
```

I tried constructing a command like this:

```
grep -irl "something" . | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo "%"; cat "%" | grep -i "another thing" "%"'
```

Explanation: `grep -l` returns the filenames. Then I print those filenames with `echo "%"` and then I want to grep inside the file.

But no luck. What is the lesson here?

To clarify: My actual problem/goal is to find all files that contain a string A but do not contain a string B as well.

More clarification: I want something like `grep A | grep -v B` but I want a list of all files that matched `A`, as well.

Comment: This (didn't test) ? 2nd xargs -> grep -irl "something" . | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo "%"; cat "%" | xargs -I % grep -i "another thing" "%"

Comment: You're sending _all_ `grep` output to `xargs`.

Comment: No I want to first grep to find some files and then grep inside those files. Your command seems to grep over all files twice.

Comment: Do you need to see the output of the first `grep`?

Comment: Kusalananda: the first grep returns the filenames (option -l) only

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your middle stage in the pipeline. Do you want to `cat` the file (send the contents of the file to the second `grep`)?

Comment: I want first to grep all files, then grep inside each file. I have added some clarifications above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/55359)

Comment: Your clarification seems to be counter to what you are actually doing and saying earlier in the question. The start of the question seems to say that you want to find files that contain matches for two patterns. You clarification seems to say that you want to find files that contain one pattern, but not another.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the lesson here?

Probably *do not over-egg the pudding*.

```
% (
>   grep -l -r -- "$patternA" . |
>   tee /dev/fd/7 |
>   xargs grep -L -- "$patternB"
> ) 7>&1
```